Failed building wheel for tflite-support for Ultralytics
I'm trying to import a YOLO model from the ultralytics package and having a few issues installing tflite-support. I've tried upgrading wheels, setuptools and ran the suggested command
pip install --use-pep517 tflite-support
I've also tried the suggestion from an earlier thread to install python 3.11 instead, but that creates a few incompatibilities with pytjon_abi, as well as other packages.
Any idea what I could do?
Here's the error code I'm getting:
Collecting tflite-support
  Using cached tflite-support-0.1.0a1.tar.gz (390 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting pybind11>=2.4 (from tflite-support)
  Using cached pybind11-2.13.6-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.5 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.7.0 in c:\users\franc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tflite-support) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\franc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tflite-support) (1.26.4)
Using cached pybind11-2.13.6-py3-none-any.whl (243 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: tflite-support
  Building wheel for tflite-support (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [84 lines of output]
      C:\Users\franc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py:80: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
              If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tflite_support
      copying tflite_support\codegen.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tflite_support
      copying tflite_support\metadata.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tflite_support
      copying tflite_support\metadata_schema_py_generated.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tflite_support
      copying tflite_support\schema_py_generated.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tflite_support
      copying tflite_support\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tflite_support
      running egg_info
      writing tflite_support.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to tflite_support.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing entry points to tflite_support.egg-info\entry_points.txt
      writing requirements to tflite_support.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to tflite_support.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'tflite_support.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      writing manifest file 'tflite_support.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      C:\Users\franc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py:204: _Warning: Package 'tflite_support.flatbuffers' is absent from the `packages` configuration.
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              ############################
              # Package would be ignored #
              ############################
              Python recognizes 'tflite_support.flatbuffers' as an importable package[^1],
              but it is absent from setuptools' `packages` configuration.

              This leads to an ambiguous overall configuration. If you want to distribute this
              package, please make sure that 'tflite_support.flatbuffers' is explicitly added
              to the `packages` configuration field.

              Alternatively, you can also rely on setuptools' discovery methods
              (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
              instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).

              You can read more about "package discovery" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html

              If you don't want 'tflite_support.flatbuffers' to be distributed and are
              already explicitly excluding 'tflite_support.flatbuffers' via
              `find_namespace_packages(...)/find_namespace` or `find_packages(...)/find`,
              you can try to use `exclude_package_data`, or `include-package-data=False` in
              combination with a more fine grained `package-data` configuration.

              You can read more about "package data files" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html


              [^1]: For Python, any directory (with suitable naming) can be imported,
                    even if it does not contain any `.py` files.
                    On the other hand, currently there is no concept of package data
                    directory, all directories are treated like packages.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        check.warn(importable)
      copying tflite_support\metadata_schema.fbs -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tflite_support
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tflite_support\flatbuffers
      copying tflite_support\flatbuffers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tflite_support\flatbuffers
      copying tflite_support\flatbuffers\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tflite_support\flatbuffers
      copying tflite_support\flatbuffers\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tflite_support\flatbuffers
      copying tflite_support\flatbuffers\encode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tflite_support\flatbuffers
      copying tflite_support\flatbuffers\number_types.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tflite_support\flatbuffers
      copying tflite_support\flatbuffers\packer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tflite_support\flatbuffers
      copying tflite_support\flatbuffers\table.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tflite_support\flatbuffers
      copying tflite_support\flatbuffers\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\tflite_support\flatbuffers
      running build_ext
      building '_pywrap_codegen' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for tflite-support
  Running setup.py clean for tflite-support
Failed to build tflite-support
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (tflite-support)```

